# Visual Basic on MS Word vs. MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

What are the differences, if there are any, between Visual Basic on MS Word vs. Visual Basic on MS Excel?

Comment: They use similar but different object models. Why do you want to know? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: If I learn VBA for excel and run a Macro on Word, using the same language, will I achieve the same result?

Comment: You will understand the concept of VBA and its general syntax, but you will not learn everything about what it can do for one of them if all you do it learn what it can do for the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it is the same language where ever you find VBA: Excel, Word, Outlook, PowerPoint etc.

If you have learned to program VBA in one of them you should be able to do it in all of them.

However as people comment on your question, there are different object models, and you will have to learn how to use them individually.

#### The easiest

Excel is by fare the easiest to get the hang of, because it is rather easy to understand the concepts of sheets and cells. And often you just want VBA to do more advanced formulas than what can be achieved in a classic cell-formula. But this is also the part that makes excel-VBA unique from the other "VBAs".

#### The second easiest

I my opinion the second easiest to learn is Outlook, because the objects you are working with are objects you are already familiar with: folders, emails, attachments etc. the structure is well known.

#### The abstract ones

Then it comes to Word and PowerPoint. It tents to be a little more difficult/abstract, because you can structure your word-document i a billion ways, and referring to the second table on page 5, is of cause doable but a lot more abstract than referring to an excel-cell. And what happens when you move the table to page 19? Hopefully nothing :-) but how did you move it? Cut/Paste or Copy/Paste and then delete the old one? A lot more can go wrong in Word-VBA than in Excel-VBA.

#### Reusing code across the VBAs

You can reuse the code in an excel-VBA, when working on a Word-VBA. Eg. moving a file from one folder to another, is the same because it is the same model being use.

#### Using Excel-VBA in Word-VBA or vice versa

Can also be done. if you open a word-file from an excel-VBA you will be able to manipulate the word-document using word-VBA from the Excel-file. the only thing you will have to do is to activate the word-library.